# android fragment imports

Tags: android, fragment, importación

Estoy intentando cargar un fragmento de mapa y tengo problema con los imports:

Si en el fragmento del mapa importo android.support.v4.app.Fragment, en el fragmento desde el que lo lanzo, me da error en el .replace porque se requiere un argumento de tipo android.app.Fragment.

```
Maps_fragment mapsf = new Maps_fragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("latitud", instalacion.Latitud);
            bundle.putString("longitud", instalacion.Longitud);
            bundle.putString("titulo", instalacion.Nombre);
            bundle.putBoolean("editable", false);
            mapsf.setArguments(bundle);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, mapsf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Sin embargo, si en el fragmento del mapa importo android.app.Fragment, me permite hacer el replace pero me encuentro el error "Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'" en la siguiente línea:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

¿Hay alguna manera de cargar el fragmento siendo android.support.v4.app.Fragment o alguna otra solución? ¡Gracias!

Comment: En vez de utilizar getFragmentManager() utiliza getsupportfragmentmanager() y debería funcionar

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo he solucionado como cuento en mi respuesta.

Comment: Juan, si no usas el soporte debes usar MapFragment, si usas soporte SupportMapFragment , en este caso usando getFragmentManager debes usar MapFragment, agrego respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado cambiando SupportMapFragment() por MapFragment()

Answer (score 0):

Juan, es muy importante saber que usando Fragments, en este caso los de Maps, **si usas [getFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()) para interactuar con los `Fragments`, en realidad debes usar [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment).**

En cambio si usas las clases de soporte uando [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager())
debes usar [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment).